# How to make powershell prompt shorter?

Tags: powershell, prompt

Bellow is sample screenshot to show my problem (marked with red):
I want to make this prompt shorter somehow without reallocating my project or folders within project.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: I hope the linked post shows you the necessary techniques to implement a custom solution; let us know if you have more specific requirements.

Comment: @mklement0 nice solution indeed! however one problem is that this will also remove `posh-git` prompt which indicates a branch context, I guess I'll need to do some additional work for this but not sure how.

Comment: I see: that's an interesting variation: Do these help? https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git#customizing-the-posh-git-prompt and https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/wiki/Customizing-Your-PowerShell-Prompt

Comment: @mklement0 thank you a lot! I'm now updating my posh-git and these customization look like exactly what I need!